# Is it possible to use Matter.js and JSON together?

Tags: javascript, json, svg, matter.js

I'm using the Matter.js engine and I want to create polygons through SVG paths.
To avoid the use of DOM/HTML, I thought about using a JSON file which contains the information that is needed.

The AJAX request and the Parsing of the JSON file do not seem to be the problem.

```
function brickletStart(text){
var jason = JSON.parse(text);
// get the info from variable d 
var path = jason.svg.path; 

createPolygon(path);
}


function createPolygon(value){
  var polygon = Matter.Bodies.fromVertices(
        400,20, Matter.Svg.pathToVertices(value, 10),{
          render: {
            fillStyle: color,
            strokeStyle: color,
            restitution: 2,
            velocity: 0.5,
            wireframes: false
          }
        }, true); 
  Matter.Composite.add(world, polygon);
  }
```

When the code gets to the function **pathToVertices(path)** I receive an error that states:

```
matter.js:10651 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'numberOfItems')
    at Svg._svgPathToAbsolute (matter.js:10651:38)
    at Svg.pathToVertices (matter.js:10593:13)
    at createPolygon (svg.js:83:28)
    at brickletStart (svg.js:77:1)
    at ajax.onreadystatechange (svg.js:65:13)
```

I don't understand why I get this TypeError, the path that I receive back from the JSON file seems to be fine and shouldn't be the problem. Or is it just not possible to use SVG paths/JSON the way I'm doing it right now because I really want to avoid using HTML for the SVG paths.

Does anyone have an idea what im doing wrong? THX (:!

Comment: `jason.svg.path` is most likely `undefined`. Why not `console.log(jason)`? _“Is it possible to use Matter.js and JSON together?”_ — AJAX is a _programming technique_; it’s impossible to cause any conflict with anything.

Comment: @SebastianSimon the `Jason.svg.path` is not undefined! It holds the value of the path: `M0,130C0,46.94,45.27,0,104.8,0C164.33,0,210,46.94,210,130C210,213.06,164.73,260,104.8,260C44.87,260,0,213.06,0,130ZM162.93,130C162.93,69.01,139.2,40.83,104.8,40.83C70.4,40.83,46.97,69.01,46.97,130C46.97,190.99,70.7,219.17,104.8,219.17C138.9,219.17,162.93,190.99,162.93,130Z` which is why I don't understand the Error that I receive.

Comment: So, it’s a string. According to the [documentation](//brm.io/matter-js/docs/classes/Svg.html#method_pathToVertices) it must be an [`SVGPathElement`](//developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/SVGPathElement).